# Unable to prevent main window scroll on focus of element within a dropdown

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm trying to use a custom drop-down menu component that shows a list of checkboxes, the size of the list can vary between users, so I've set a max height and overflow to auto to allow scrolling if the list gets very long. The problem I've run into is that when checking one of the boxes near the bottom of the list, the main window scrolls down as if it's focusing the checkbox if it wasn't contained within the dropdown, so it will scroll to the bottom of the page.

[Showing dropdown component with checkboxes inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bA0j.png)

dropdown component:

```
        <div ref={ref} style={{ position: 'absolute', listStyle: 'none', zIndex: 9999 }}>
            <Region>  {/* Region adds the animation for opening */}
                <Card className="custom-simple-list"> {/* Override the overflow and margins/padding */}
                    <CheckboxGroup className="margin-bottom-0" label="">
                        {props.items.map((item) => (
                            <Checkbox key={item[1]} label={item[1]} id={item[0]} value={item[0]} checked={props.checkedFunc(item[0])}  onChange={() => props.onChange(item[0])}> </Checkbox>
                        ))}
                    </CheckboxGroup>
                    <Button variant="link" onClick={props.clearAll}>Clear All</Button>
                </Card>
            </Region>
        </div>
```

css:

```
.custom-simple-list {
  margin: 0px !important;
  padding: 25px 25px 0px 15px !important;
  max-height: 20rem !important;
  overflow: auto !important; /* Scrollbar if items are too long */
}
```

I'm not sure what other code would be helpful,and the Checkbox components within mine are from a component library that I'm unable to view the source code for from what I can tell.

I've tried e.stopPropagation() and e.preventDefault() on basically all events for the Checkbox component that I can think of. Nothing seems to stop the automatic scrolling down.

I'd expect e.preventDefault() to stop the browser from trying to scroll to the focused element, since it's seemingly treating the element as if it's not contained within a dropdown with it's own scroll...

Comment: Could you please include a minimal reproducible code. It looks like you are triggering scroll on checkbox change. could you please show more part of your implementation

Comment: I am guessing that what your screenshot shows, are not the _actual_ checkbox inputs, but "replacements" - because checkboxes are hard to format. So this component most likely uses the common technique of styling these replacements based on the `:checked` status of the checkboxes, but _hides_ the actual checkbox inputs. And that hiding is often not done via display:none (because that would make the whole thing hard to use for screenreader users), but uses a combination of clip-path and position: absolute. [...]

Comment: [...] So most likely all your checkbox inputs are positioned at the bottom somewhere, and that explains the window scrolling there. In that case, you would either need to find a different way of hiding them; or maybe add position:relative to whatever the immediate parent is, so that they stay in that place, and don't move elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks CBroe. The only thing that makes me question that theory is the fact that checking most of the boxes doesn't cause any issue, it's only the checkboxes near the bottom of the scroll in the dropdown menu. But I guess that would make sense if these phantom checkboxes were spilling out of my dropdown menu. Would there be a way to make sure any "phantom" checkboxes are always contained within my dropdown menu and don't spill out?

Comment: That was it CBroe! Thank you so much. I added this css class to the parent div of the checkboxes: ```.contain-children * {
  position: relative;

} ```and everything is now contained within, which stops the scrolling. I was pulling my hair out over this, I appreciate you taking the time to share your wisdom/experience, I had no idea about the common practice of using fake checkboxes and "storing" the real ones somewhere, so never would have thought of that. I'm not sure how to mark this as answered since it's a comment.